# Can you get a refund either RP or IP on a champion if you do not like them?

Tags: league-of-legends

I bought a champion the other day with RP and I'm not particularly fond of them. Does Riot state a return policy (I didn't notice one) on refunding a champ for the price that I paid for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you e-mail riot support they are usually willing to give ONE refund if you ask nicely, but this is rare because they are not supposed to.

Answer (score 8):

There is now [in-game support for refunding](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/news/new-refund-feature-available-now) up to 3 champions or skins, no need to contact Riot support. You get back the same currency used to purchase them (RP/IP).

Here are the full limitations, according to Riot's page:

> - You only get three refunds per account, per lifetime
> - You can only refund skins and champions, not runes, boosts, or bundles
> - We can only refund a purchase that you’ve made in the last 90 days, so no hocking last year’s promotional skins back to us!
> - If you own a champion and some of their skins, you need to return the skins before you can get a refund on the champion

Comment: Actually, I think you can, but you have to refund the skin first, then the champion. Which of course takes away one refund credit, each time.

Comment: Also, you cannot refund any champion bundles either strangely

Answer (score 1):

You can get a refund addition times if you bought a champ with IP/RP but then promise them that you are going to buy a champion bundle that includes that champion but hesitate because you spent IP/RP already on part of the bundle.  This also involves e-mailing someone in Riot, and is done so on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 0):

You get a 1 time refund on anything... use it well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are able to get one refund but normally its when a champion goes on sale or is reduced with in 24 hours of purchase.